# Is the usage of "successful" in "Was John successful practicing golf and surfing?" correct?

Tags: word-usage

> Was John *successful* practicing golf and surfing?

I think **successful** is an adjective . In this case it must be an adverb. So I think **successfully** should be used instead of **successful**. 
And this sentence is: Was John successfully practicing golf and surfing?

Comment: There's a preposition missing, either "**in**","**at**" or maybe even "**while**"

Comment: **Successful** is a predicate adjective applied to the subject **John**.  We could also say **successfully** there, though perhaps not with those particular verbs.  Was John happy writing software?  Was John happily writing software?  The former could refer to John's occupation/job.  The latter could refer to John's activity at a particular moment, or over a period of time.

Comment: **Was John happy writing software?**
I don't think it is correct. I think the correct must be :
**Was John happily writing software?**

Comment: @PhamVanDuc Actually, "*Was John happy writing software?*" is grammatically sound. You can think of it as an elaboration to "*Was John happy?*" That is, did *writing software* make John happy? This is subtly different from the *happily* version, which simply describes John's emotions while writing software. Idiomatically, the *happily* version normally carries the sense that John was minding his own business (when something happened).

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are a bit difficult since, at times, they might be loosely used interchangeably

> Was John **successful practicing** golf?
>   *Was John successful* ***to*** *practice golf*?

this sentence concerns itself with the *ability to practice* and might be used if there was a question about John being able to practice, for example it was near closing time or a holiday.

> Was John **successfully practicing** golf?
>   *Was John successful* ***with*** *his golf practice*?
>   *Was John able to improve his golf through practice*?

this sentence concerns itself with how the practice itself went.

Answer (score 0):

I think you received some great advice on how this works grammatically in the comments on your post, but this whole sentence is a little odd, specifically because "practice" has a dual meaning. It can mean you do something as a vocation, or it can mean you just keep doing something to get better at it. If I want to know whether someone is successful at the vocations of golf and surfing, I'd probably leave out the word "practicing" altogether. In other words, "Was John successful at golf and surfing." Otherwise, it's really ambiguous.